# Help with understanding map in Rotman's Introduction to Homological Algebra

Tags: modules, homological-algebra

This may be a simple problem, but I'm stuck on it and I've been banging my head against the wall the past few days over this. I'm reading through Rotman's *Introduction to Homological Algebra* and I'm stuck on the statement of Theorem 2.30. The theorem states:

> **Theorem 2.30** Let R be a ring, A a left R-module, and let $(B_i)_{i \in I}$ be a family of left R-modules.
>
> > (i) There is a Z(R)-isomorphism $\phi: Hom_R(A, \Pi_{i \in I} B_i )\to \Pi_{i \in I} Hom_R(A,B_i)$ with $\phi:f \mapsto(p_i f)$ where $p_i$ are the projections of the direct product $\Pi_{i\in I}B_i$.
> >
> > (ii) The isomorphism is natural: if $(C_j)_{j \in J}$ is a family of left R-modules and, for each $i \in I$ there exist $j \in J$ and an R-map $\sigma_{ij}:B_i \to C_j$, then there is a commutative diagram

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
Hom_R(A,\Pi_{i\in I} B_i) @>{\sigma_*}>> Hom_R(A,\Pi_{j \in J}C_j) \\
@VVV @VVV\\
\Pi_{i \in I}Hom_R(A,B_i) @>{\widetilde{\sigma}}>>\Pi_{j \in J}Hom_R(A,C_j)
\end{CD}

> > where the vertical maps are $\phi$, the map $\sigma: \Pi_{i\in I}B_i \to \Pi_{j \in J}$ is given by $(b_i)\mapsto (\sigma_{ij}b_i)$, and $\tilde{\sigma}:(g_i)\mapsto (\sigma_{ij}g_i)$.

Where I'm running into trouble is in understanding the map $\sigma$, it doesn't seem well-defined to me. For example, if $I = \{1,2\}$ and $J=\{1\}$ then what is $\sigma(b_1,b_2)$? It seems like it could be either $\sigma_{1,1}(b_1)$ or $\sigma_{2,1}(b_2)$, but this isn't well-defined unless there are further conditions on $\sigma_{ij}$ that the Theorem doesn't specify.

I could use some help here. I'm not sure if I'm reading something incorrectly or not making an assumption I should be making, can someone help guide me to the right way to understand this map $\sigma$?

Comment: If you add a condition like, "for each $j$, there are only finitely many maps $\sigma_{ij}$," then the map $\sigma$ should just add up the various terms: the $j$th component will be $\sigma_{i_1, j} b_{i_1} + \sigma_{i_2, j} b_{i_2} + ...$. Without such a condition, I agree that there are some problems.

Comment: That works! It's well-defined and this definition makes the diagram commute, thank you!